# Can't register my Nesica card with Groove Coaster?

Tags: arcade, groove-coaster

**Update 11/29/2022:** I was finally able to register my card just now. Left out the underscore and used the full width characters and was able to register. I think I lucked out because either my account finally timed out or I tried playing after an update. When I played the game, it asked if I wanted to migrate my account and was able to change my name then. Though being in PST and playing later in the night, it seemed to require a date in JST so had to pick the date after when I played.

---

**Update 07/30/2022:** tried again after over 2 weeks since I last tried at a different arcade. The Groove Coaster machine there was online and recognized my card and got my progress, but trying to register still did not work. I'll have to look out for other games that I could use the card on and try my luck with those. I think trying to link my card with just Groove Coaster is a lost cause at this point.

---

A nearby arcade has a Groove Coaster machine that's connected online and sells Nesica cards. I have been able to use it in the game and it seems to have recognized and saved my progress so all seems good.

However when I try to register my card with my account, I cannot complete registration since because I get "The card name is invalid" (カード名が不正です) error. In the game, I registered with the name "Appl_Jax" and I fear the underscore is causing problems.

How can I register my card now?

As far as I can tell, I cannot change the name associated with the card in the game, and the site just refuses to accept my card info. Or perhaps I'm going through the wrong settings? I tried using different underscore characters, just in case it only recognized a particular one, I tried changing the date to what is technically tomorrow for me and that didn't work either. The name itself seems to be correct because if I try any other name, I get a "Could not authenticate." (認証できませんでした。) error. I guess I need to wait two weeks for the system to forget about my info and try again?

[image: registration jp]

Translated:

[image: translated]

---

[image: error jp]

Translated:

[image: translated]

Comment: To be clear, I played around 8pm-10pm PDT (-7:00) on 13 of July. Maybe time zones could have played a part in this, but changing the date around didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Also tried putting in Groove Coaster Series for the "other game" and that didn't help. The dropdown as far as I can tell doesn't have another "groove coaster" entry that I might be confusing.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? Im in the exact same situation..

Comment: @Insaniac unfortunately no not yet. I did go back to the another arcade today that had groove coaster after about two weeks since the last time I went and used the card. I'll try again to see if it works out. Unfortunately the game still recognized my card and my original name so wasn't able to change it, but hopefully going to another location would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, it didn't seem to like something about the name I used, the card I had, where I played, when I played, or a combination of the four. I was finally able to register my card.

When I registered, I used the name I wanted but without the underscore and full width characters, and picked the date after the day I played considering I'm in PST and it was expecting JST date. Also, when I played, I happened to play after an update which required a migration of some sort so I was able to change my name then. Also played on a completely new machine that I haven't tried. So unless you're willing to risk it, try to keep the name as simple as possible and mind the date.

Answer (score 1):

Native Japanese here.

There's nothing wrong with using underscore, but you have to use full-width character (which is, I believe, no way to type it in English keyboard).

Try it with "Ａｐｐｌ＿Ｊａｘ" and see if it succeeds.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Looks like it's the same error unfortunately. Can you confirm that the settings appear to be correct? Groove Coaster was the only game I was able to use the card with so I chose that as the "final game" and none for "other games."

Comment: @JeffMercado Yeah, I think it's correct. Maybe what you said in comments (the time zone one) is doing something here. JST is GMT+9, so maybe change it to 14th of July and see if that works?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to no avail. This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GrooveCoaster/comments/4s1p9a/nesica_card_assistance/) seems to indicate that it would work if I tried later on in my time zone. I'll try again after 12 hours or so.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. OK, tell me if it worked. By the way, what's the reason behind your area of residence being Hokkaido? The guide that your link has (just in case you didn't notice, it's [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/GrooveCoaster/comments/4pr92a/comment/d4odm9a/) comment) is suggesting to set the area of residence to "その他"(Others; generally means overseas).

Comment: Yeah, at the time I didn't know of the "Other" option so I just picked whatever was on top. Perhaps I should default to what's on the bottom if I'm unsure. Can't seem to edit it at this point.

Comment: So I just tried again, just a little over 24 hours since I last tried and same error. I'm fairly certain that the system as currently implemented was probably not expecting some of the characters used. And the only character that would have a problem would be the non-letter character (the underscore). Tried changing case, full-/half-width, nothing's working. I guess I'll have to try to get the name changed by waiting 2 weeks and play to try again. BTW, I reregistered to change the area I live to "others" and no difference.

Comment: @JeffMercado That's sad. Though I still think using underscore is fine since the [ranking](https://groovecoaster.jp/ranking/#all) has so many non-letter character, some of them even has emojis (and of course there's user that has underscore in their name). Thanks for the catch-up.

Comment: It may be a problem caused by the combination of me being outside of Japan, the machine(s) I've played on, and the browsers I'm using to register, or the specific card I'm using, and of course the name that may be affecting this. And with my poking and prodding the registration site, it's revealing to me that it isn't the most robust website when it comes to validating inputs. So I can see why any break in those could break the whole registration process.

Comment: Went back to the arcade to try again over the weekend and try to register and still didn't work. I guess I should have not used it so I can let the data expire so I can set up a new name. Another thing probably worth mentioning is that the card I obtained apparently is the older version (the blue card). Could also be a factor as to why I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: @JeffMercado I suspect that can't interrupt this situation. I am also using old type card, but I was able to register the card (it was this year's June so I don't think they've changed the rules or something). The reason they've decided to make it new design/card is that so it can be used at Konami/Bandai Namco/SEGA and Taito's games with just one card (see [Amusement IC](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amusement_IC) if you want to know more about it, though there's no English version of the page). Migrating to a new card is recommended but not required (at least as of now).

Comment: Well, I was finally able to register my card just now. Left out the underscore and used the full width characters and was able to register. I think I lucked out because either my account finally timed out or I tried playing after an update. When I played the game, it asked if I wanted to migrate my account and was able to change my name then.